# CSS ::Before is breaking the line

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-element

I am not very experienced in CSS, I searched on the web and I couldn't find a solution for this problem. For some reason, the ::before and text are not staying in the same line. I have another template and it works fine.

I tried "white-space: nowrap" but it doesn't work. I changed to inline-block display, it works, but it changes all the spacing from Flex. I am trying to understand why this happened, and why the same code is causing different effects. I am following a tutorial on YouTube and I copy the code step by step, but the result is not the same.
My page:
[image]
His page:
[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 1.5rem;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 3 0;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border: 1px solid #ffbbbb;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: .5rem;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

ul li img {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 100rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}

ul li div {
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li div:not(:first-child) {
  flex-basis: 18%;
}

ul li select {
  width: 3rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  font-weight: 100;
}

ul .remove-button {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: none;
  padding: .5rem;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  opacity: .7;
  outline: none;
}

ul .remove-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 3;
  height: 20rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffbbbb;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.checkout>div {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.checkout .foods-count {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.checkout .foods-count::before {
  content: 'Count: ';
  color: grey;
}

.checkout .total-price::before {
  content: 'Price: ';
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let cartItem of cart.items">
      <div>
        <img [src]="cartItem.food.imageUrl" [alt]="cartItem.food.name" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <a [routerLink]="['/food/', cartItem.food.id]">
          {{ cartItem.food.name }}
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select #quantitySelect (change)="changeQuantity(cartItem, quantitySelect.value)">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ cartItem.price | currency }}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="remove-button" (click)="removeFromCart(cartItem)">
          Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="checkout">
    <div class="foods-count">
      {{ cart.items.length }}
    </div>
    <div class="total-price">
      {{ cart.totalPrice | currency }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.checkout>div {flex-direction: column}` But honestly, I wouldn't put important content in a `::before`

Comment: The code may give problems for those using assistive technology. For example they may not hear the word price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, that `flex-direction:column` also affects `::before`s (and `::after`s). Remove that, and... Well, now there isn't a space between the `::before` and the element. This can be fixed by adding a no-break space `\00a0` at the end of the `::before`'s `content`.

Here's the correct code:

```css
/* ... */
.checkout>div {
  /* ... */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* ... */
}
/* ... */
.checkout .foods-count::before { content: 'Count:\00a0' }
.checkout .total-price::before { content: 'Price:\00a0' }
.checkout :is(.foods-count, .total-price)::before { 
  display: inline;
  color: gray;
}
```

The `:is(` is just a shorthand for both of the `::before`s.

And here's the full snippet:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 1.5rem;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 3 0;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  border: 1px solid #ffbbbb;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: .5rem;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}

ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

ul li img {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  border-radius: 100rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}

ul li div {
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li div:not(:first-child) {
  flex-basis: 18%;
}

ul li select {
  width: 3rem;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  font-weight: 100;
}

ul .remove-button {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  border: none;
  padding: .5rem;
  color: var(--primary-color);
  opacity: .7;
  outline: none;
}

ul .remove-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 3;
  height: 20rem;
  border: 1px solid #ffbbbb;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.checkout>div {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.checkout .foods-count {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.checkout .foods-count::before { content: 'Count:\00a0 ' }
.checkout .total-price::before { content: 'Price:\00a0 ' }
.checkout :is(.foods-count, .total-price)::before {
  display: inline;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let cartItem of cart.items">
      <div>
        <img [src]="cartItem.food.imageUrl" [alt]="cartItem.food.name" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <a [routerLink]="['/food/', cartItem.food.id]">
          {{ cartItem.food.name }}
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select #quantitySelect (change)="changeQuantity(cartItem, quantitySelect.value)">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
          <option>5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ cartItem.price | currency }}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="remove-button" (click)="removeFromCart(cartItem)">
          Remove
        </button>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="checkout">
    <div class="foods-count">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="total-price">
      $4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```